# Why does Xcode not see the Parse framework on second session?

Tags: parse-platform, xcode6

"No such module 'Parse'" is an error I get on the "import Parse" line of my Swift project. Latest Xcode and OSX.

The Bolts and Parse framework files are located in my library. Deleting their references and relinking them into the project fixes it for that session, but on subsequent launches of Xcode, I get the error again. I can even just go to Build Phases then remove and readd Bolts/Parse and it'll work, don't even have to remove the file references in the Project Navigator pane.

Cleaning the project doesn't help.

Is this a Parse bug, or something that's wrong with my project?

Comment: Did you import the Bolt's framework

Comment: Yes, I did. Both Parse and Bolts are in there.

Comment: Are you using Swift?